# How do I use read_scanline from the piston image crate?

Tags: rust

I just started learning Rust and I really like to learn by building something 'real'. So I read through the [Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), installed Rust, played around with the language and got `cargo run` working.

I then decided to try and read an image from disk and convert that image into a `Vec`. In this case, I want to detect the color of the pixels and store that somehow.

I broke it into multiple parts to learn Rust and its syntax:

Starting with:

1. Read an image from disk
2. Get the pixels of an image
3. Show colour code

This led me to the following code using [the image crate](http://www.piston.rs/image/image):

```
extern crate image;

use std::path::Path;
use image::GenericImage;

fn main() {

    let img = image::open(&Path::new("src/maze.gif")).unwrap();

    let pixels = img.pixels();

    for e in pixels {
        let (_, _, color) = e;

        println!("Pixel colour {:?}", color);
    }

    println!("Dimensions {:?}", img.dimensions());
}
```

So proud as I am, I see some information popping up:

```
* snip *
Pixel colour Rgba { data: [255, 255, 255, 255] }
Pixel colour Rgba { data: [0, 0, 0, 255] }
Pixel colour Rgba { data: [255, 255, 255, 255] }
* snip *
```

Now I want to store for each line of the image its pixel information. I would like to have a `Vec` (is that correct?) with the info. A PHP array would look like this:

```
$a = [
   0 => [ Color, Color, Color, Color],
   1 => [ Color, Color, Color, Color]
];
```

Therefore my assumption is to use [`read_scanline`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.ImageDecoder.html#tymethod.read_scanline). This is where reading AND understanding the documentation fails me completely.

What I think I need to do is:

1. Get the decoder for the current opened image
2. Call `read_scanline` on that decoder
3. Iterate over the results

But how?!

The code reads this:

```
read_scanline(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> ImageResult<u32>
```

I break this down as follows:

- First argument, an `ImageDecoder` object.
- Second argument a mutable 8 bit value.
- It returns an `ImageResult` object.

So I tried adapting the code slightly:

```
extern crate image;

use std::path::Path;
use image::GenericImage;
use image::ImageDecoder;

fn main() {

    let img = image::open(&Path::new("src/maze.gif")).unwrap();

    let pixels = img.pixels();
    let something: &mut [u8];
    let result = image::ImageDecoder::read_scanline(img, something);

    for e in pixels {
        let (_, _, color) = e;

        println!("Pixel colour {:?}", color);
    }

    println!("Dimensions {:?}", img.dimensions());
}
```

Which, as you might have guessed fails miserably.

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut _`,
    found `image::dynimage::DynamicImage`
(expected &-ptr,
    found enum `image::dynimage::DynamicImage`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:13     let result = image::ImageDecoder::read_scanline(img, something);
```

Obviously this is due to the fact I didn't pass an `ImageDecoder` object. But how can I? How should I read and understand the documentation. I think it is due to not understanding `&mut self`. I also do not understand how I should initiate this.

I hope someone can explain what it is I am missing and point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note** I'm having trouble actually opening a GIF as each line says it is 0 bytes, so there's the possibility I've missed something important... I'll use a JPEG to demonstrate instead.

`ImageDecoder` is [a trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/traits.html). You need to use a concrete implementation of the trait. The documentation lists all known implementors of the trait, one of which is [`image::gif::Decoder`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/gif/struct.Decoder.html), another is [`image::jpeg::JPEGDecoder`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/jpeg/struct.JPEGDecoder.html).

`read_scanline` accepts a mutable `self`, which means that you normally will call it with *method syntax*: `object.method(arg1)`. The first non-`self` argument is a mutable slice of bytes. The documentation states:

> Reads one row from the image into `buf` and returns the row index

So the pixel data will be stored in the buffer. The next trick is to figure out how many bytes we need for a row and how many rows there are. [`ImageDecoder::row_len`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.ImageDecoder.html#tymethod.row_len)  and [`ImageDecoder::dimensions`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.ImageDecoder.html#tymethod.dimensions) address that respectively. Put together, we get something like this:

```
extern crate image;

use std::fs::File;

use image::jpeg;
use image::{GenericImage, ImageDecoder};
use image::{ColorType, Rgb, Pixel};

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("/tmp/cat.jpg").unwrap();
    let mut decoder = jpeg::JPEGDecoder::new(f);

    let (width, height) = decoder.dimensions().unwrap();
    let row_len = decoder.row_len().unwrap();

    println!("{} x {}, {}", width, height, row_len);

    let rows: Vec<_> = (0..height).map(|_| {
        let mut row = vec![0; row_len];
        decoder.read_scanline(&mut row).unwrap();
        row
    }).collect();
}
```

This loads the JPEG, row-by-row, into a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` - a vector of vectors of bytes.

To convert the raw data into pixels, we can use [`Pixel::from_slice`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.Pixel.html#tymethod.from_slice), another trait method. In this case, I only handle one type of pixel - 8-bit RGB:

```
let colortype = decoder.colortype().unwrap();
assert_eq!(colortype, ColorType::RGB(8)); // Others are left to you!

let row_colors: Vec<Vec<_>> = rows.iter().map(|r| {
    r.chunks(3).map(|p| Rgb::from_slice(p)).collect()
}).collect();
```

I'm not in love with this because of the hard-coded `3`. There should be some way of knowing that this pixel type only takes 3 bytes, but I'm not seeing anything obvious.

Comment: This information really helped me understand some of the lingo much better.